# Negative line break command

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

Is there a command for a "negative line break" or for deleting line breaks? Something like `-\\` such that:

`some\\ -\\ \\ \\text`

would display the same as

`some\\ \\text`

Comment: I guess, if you provide an optional argument to ``\\`` that might be a start `Some text \\ \\[-2\baselineskip] Some text` produces two `Some text`s perfectly overlapped for me, but you will read many people implore you not to use ``\\`` except in those limited cases it was intended for, such as tables.  Can you give us more information as to what you're trying to achieve, because ``\\`` is not supposed to be used very much

Comment: you should never have two consecutive `\\ ` so in what cases would you need 4 of them to act like two?

Comment: @Au101 Thank you, `\\[-2\baselineskip]` is what I need. Could you please post that as answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Some text \\ \\[-2\baselineskip] Other text` makes a negative line break, per Au101's comment.